# android.support.v7.app.ActionBar & android.app.ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, tabview

I was trying to create an app with tab but i got the error..pls help..

when I use **'ActionBar actionBar'** and got error at this line of code :
`actionBar = getActionBar(); -> incompatible type`.
and when i use **android.app.ActionBar** actionBar I got error at this line :

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); -> error
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabNames[i])
                    .setTabListener(this)); -> error
        }



app module :<br>
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


        defaultConfig {
            useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
}
```

tabActivity

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class tabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter tabPagerAdapter;
    private android.app.ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabNames = { "First", "Second"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabActivity);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        tabPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabNames[i])
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int postion) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(postion);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Mn_Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabActivity"
            android:label="TAB" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FragmentActivity` try extending `AppCompatActivity` and instead of `getActionBar()` use `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: Or add `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` in styles

Comment: @Sourabh , i had try as u suggest but still not working..
thanks

Comment: Can you post your `styles.xml`

Comment: @Lim YC did you try accessing ACTION_BAR feature as I suggested?

Comment: n.arrow001 yeah i have tried but not working...
@Sourabh here is my styles.xml
 <resources>
    <style name="AppTheme"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>

Comment: remove these two items and try again: `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> `

Answer (score 0):

if you want Tab you can try this.

```
TabHost th = getTabHost();

        //Tab 1
        TabSpec tab1= th.newTabSpec("Tab Name");
        tab1.setIndicator("Frame Anim", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic));
        Intent move = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FrameAnimation.class);
        tab1.setContent(move);
        //Tab 2
        TabSpec tab2= th.newTabSpec("Tab Name");
        tab2.setIndicator("Tween Amin", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic));
        Intent movetween = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TweenAnimations.class);
        tab2.setContent(movetween); 
        th.addTab(tab1);
        th.addTab(tab2);
```

and add TabHost in layout file.